# Why character increment expression in kotlin not working in first attempt?

Tags: kotlin, character

I got confuse for the result of the code below.

```
fun main() {
    var vocal = 'A'
    println("Vocal " + vocal++)
    println("Vocal " + vocal++)
    println("Vocal " + vocal++)
    println("Vocal " + vocal--)
    println("Vocal " + vocal--)
    println("Vocal " + vocal--)
    println("Vocal " + vocal--)
}
```

Result:

```
Vocal A
Vocal B
Vocal C
Vocal D
Vocal C
Vocal B
Vocal A
```

In line 3 (vocal++) I expected the result is 'B' but instead the result is 'A'. Why is it not increment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you put `++` or `--` after the variable name, it's called postincrement or postdecrement, and means that the returned value is the old one. To get the new value instead, you need to preincrement or predecrement, so do `++vocal` and `--vocal` instead of `vocal++` and `vocal--`.